# python - is it possible to enter user-chosen input and output files

Tags: python, user-input, stdin

I'm a newbie in python, so please bear with me.

I don't know how to describe,so I'll just show an example.

```
python CODE.py -i1 input1.txt -i2 input2.txt -o output.txt
```

Is such thing possible with python? I've looked up for a while but haven't find an answer.

Thank you!

Comment: Try [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just linking to the [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) or the [argparse tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/argparse.html),
the other respondents probably should have just shown you how to do it:

```
import argparse

# Build the parser
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='CODE.PY')
p.add_argument('-i1', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
               metavar='sourcefile1', help='First input file')
p.add_argument('-i2', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
               metavar='sourcefile2', help='Second input file')
p.add_argument('-o', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
               metavar='destfile', help='Destination filename')

# Parse sys.argv
ns = p.parse_args()

# Use the files
data1 = ns.i1.read()
data2 = ns.i2.read()
result = data1[:10] + data2[:10]
ns.o.write(result)
```

A nice feature of argparse is that not only does it build parsers, it creates a nice option for command-line help:

```
$ python CODE.PY -h

usage: CODE.PY [-h] [-i1 sourcefile1] [-i2 sourcefile2] [-o destfile]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  -i1 sourcefile1  First input file
  -i2 sourcefile2  Second input file
  -o destfile      Destination filename
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code perfectly worked, but when I tried to modify I got tons of error messages. Anyway, would you explain what does 'ns' mean in 'data1 = ns.i1.read()'?

Comment: The variable ``ns`` is for the namespace object returned by the parser.  The attribute lookup ``ns.i1`` looks-up the file object for the *i1* source file.  The ``ns.i1.read()`` reads the data from the *i1* source file.

Answer (score 1):

As [thefourtheye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903116/thefourtheye) said you can used argparse module. But if you want simple solution, just pass 2 inputs and output file paths as arguments to your executable and use `sys.argv` to get them in your program in order. The `sys.argv[0]` is your application name, `sys.argv[1]` is first input file path, `sys.argv[2]` is second input file path and `sys.argv[3]` is output file path.

```
import sys
input1 = sys.argv[1]
input2 = sys.argv[2]
output = sys.argv[3]
```

now you can call like below:

```
python my_app.py /path/to/input1.txt /path/to/input2.txt /path/to/output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use system argument with your code.

Following snippet of code might help you to resolve your problem

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('inFile', nargs=2, help="Choose in file to use")    
parser.add_argument('outFile', nargs=1, help="Choose out file to use")  
args=parser.parse_args()                                                 
your_fun_call( args.inFile , args.outFile[0] )
```

Might look wierd at first look but you can refer this document
[argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)

**Note:** infile argument has nargs as 2 because you want two input
 files ( nargs stands for number of argument)